# Section in greek is not bold

Tags: sectioning, greek

I am trying to write the solution to some exercises in greek, but I cannot get the section to be bold and underlined if I use greek letters. It might be worth noting that:

1. It works fine if I use `\textlatin{Ex 1}`
2. Using `\section*{\pmb{\underline{Άσκηση 1}}}` gives me exactly what I am looking for

Here is my code with all the packages I am using:

```
% Set the font (output) encoding
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
% Greek-specific commands
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino font
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Λήμμα}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section*{Άσκηση 1}}
Καλημέρα
\end{document}
```

Comment: We do you load two times package `amsmath` and package `geometry`  and `fontenc`? You could use `\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}` . You shoudn't load `inputenc` at all. It seems that loading `mathpazo` and `tgtermes`  font packages cause the problem. If you comment their lines the problem goes away. Are you sure that they are compatible with LGR encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the suggestion of the user @miltos: I have put `\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}` and I shoudn't load inputenc at all. The problem it is the sovrapposition of mathpazo and tgtermes font packages that cause the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
% Greek-specific commands
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Λήμμα}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section*{Άσκηση 1}
Καλημέρα \textbf{Καλημέρα}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebatiano:It seems that `\textbf` does not work at all after the loading of `mathpazo` and `tgtermes` packages. Some incompatibility arises with these fonts and LGR encoding. If you try to make the word `Καλημέρα` bold using `\textbf{Καλημέρα}` fails.

Comment: @miltos Now I try again. Thank you very much.

Comment: @miltos Done! You had right.

Comment: Thank you @miltos and @Sebastiano for your suggestions! I am a newbie in latex, so I took the `mathpazo`, `tgterms` and `inputenc` packages from a reference latex code I was following. Your patched work fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a font family that supports the Greek alphabet, but `mathpazo` doesn't, nor does `tgtermes`.

By the way, it's rather strange to use Times (which `tgtermes` provides a clone of) for text and Palatino (provided by `mathpazo`) for math.

If you don't know what a package does, don't load it.

If you look in the log file, you find

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/qtm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 18.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/qtm/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/qtm/m/n' instead on input line 25.
```

The first warning is the most important: it tells you that the font family `qtm` (from `tgtermes`) doesn't support the LGR (Greek) encoding, so it substitutes it with a default, in this case the Beccari fonts that are known to LaTeX as `cmr` for LGR.

The next warning is similar: when LaTeX wants to set the section title, it tries boldface, but realizes that there is no bold LGR font in the `qtm` family, so it substitutes it with the alias it had created on the fly at the time of the first warning. No boldface.

If your document uses math, you need to choose a font family that supports both Greek and math. If you want (a clone of) Times, you can use Tempora for text and NewTX for math.

I had to change the order of package loading, because `amsmath` and `amssymb` (loaded by `prooftrees`) have to be before `newtxmath`.

I left `geometry`, but the setting of a 0.5in margin is rather bizarre.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\usepackage{tempora,newtxmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Λήμμα}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}

\begin{document}

\section*{Άσκηση 1}

Καλημέρα $a+b=c$

\end{document}
```

[image]